# A possible alternative to the Axioms of Pair, Union, Infinity and Replacement

Tags: logic, set-theory, relations, axioms

In this question we assume that all formulae are in the language of $\sf ZFC$ and that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent.

Recall that we say that a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ represents a [*set-like*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Relations_over_a_set) class relation iff for every $x$ the class of all $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$ forms a set (for example, $y\in x,\,y\subset x,\,x=y,\,y=\varnothing$ are set-like, but $x\in y,\,x\ne y,\,x=x$ are not).

Consider the following proposition schema (we may call it the Schema of Transitive Closure for set-like relations):

> For every set-like relation $\varphi$ and every set $u$ there is a set $v$ that is a superset of $u$ and is closed under $\varphi$. More formally, if $\varphi$ does not have any of the variables $z, u, v$ free,
>   $$\forall x\exists z\forall y\left[\varphi(x,y)\Rightarrow y\in z\right]\,\Rightarrow\,\forall u\exists v\left[u\subseteq v\land\forall x\forall y\left(x\in v\land\varphi(x,y)\Rightarrow y\in v\right)\right]$$

If we add this schema as an axiom and drop the usual axioms of Pair, Union, Infinity and Replacement, can we prove the dropped axioms as theorems in this theory? Is this theory equivalent to $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: This is off-topic, but I find the name somewhat missleading. Neither $u$ nor the relation $(u, \{(x,y) \mid x \in u \wedge y \in u \wedge \phi(x,y) \})$ is transitive in general. While I'm not happy with it either, I'd prefer something along the lines of "Schema of Set-Like Closure" or "Schema of Transitive Hulls".

Comment: Let me also add to the off topic comment by @Stefan, usually set-like means that $\varphi(\cdot,x)$ is a set for all $x$, rather than $\varphi(x,\cdot)$. You can remember this by noting that $x\in y$ is set-like, but not according to your definition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that the opposite order of parameters would look more natural. I was just following the definition from the Wikipedia.

Comment: Then you misread the definition, since Wikipedia is in agreement with me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly a consequence of ZFC: for $\varphi$ set-like and "initial set" $u$, we can define by induction the sets $u_n$ for each $n\in\omega$ as $u_0=u$, $u_{n+1}=u_n\cup\{y: \exists x\in u_n(\varphi(x, y))\}$; and we can show that the sequence $\langle u_i\rangle_{i\in\omega}$ exists (and hence the desired "$u_\omega$") by Replacement.

As to its consequences:

- It implies Replacement over $Z$: given an instance $\varphi, u$ of Replacement, consider the formula $\varphi'$ gotten by restricting $\varphi$ to $u$.
- It implies Infinity over $Z-Inf$: take $\varphi$ to define the ordinal successor (if the input is an ordinal, and $0$ otherwise), and apply to $\{\emptyset\}$.

Now let "$(*)$" be "For all $x$, $\{x\}$ is a set." Note that $(*)$ is usually proved by Pairing; in lieu of Pairing, it sees we need $(*)$ to do anything interesting:

- It implies Pairing over Separation + $(*)$: given $a, b$, consider $\varphi: x\mapsto b$, applied to $\{a\}$.
- It implies Union over $(*)$ + Separation: consider the formula $\varphi(a, b)\iff b\in a$.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like $(*)$ follows from Powerset + Separation. $\{x\}\subset\mathcal P(x)$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov That's right, I misread your question and thought you were also interested in getting rid of Powerset.

Comment: So, by taking the Extensionality, Foundation, Separation, Powerset, Choice and the Transitive Closure as axioms, we get a theory equivalent to $\sf ZFC$, right?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yup, looks like it.

Comment: The Transitive Closure looks "nicer" to me than the Pair, Union and Infinity, probably because those seem very _ad hoc_, choosing apparently "randomly" 3 ways of set formation among many other possibilities.

Comment: @Vladimir: These axioms are not ad hoc at all. They come to describe our intuitive understanding of what sets should do. For example, there is an infinite set, the natural numbers are an infinite set and we expect this to hold in the universe of sets. We also expect our universe to be closed under unions, because if we have a set of sets, we expect the union to be a set also. And so on.

Comment: Of course, they correspond to some operations that we intuitively feel to be possible to do with sets. My point is why these particular 3 operations? Why pair and not triple? Why this particular form of an infinite set? Why not to postulate existence of the set of all hereditary finite sets, for example? I understand that the selected axioms turn out to be sufficient, and they are quite simple, so they look like a reasonable choice after all. But I did not find them aesthetically pleasing, and was looking for a more general principle that would imply them. It's only about my personal feelings.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov You might be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404966/harvey-friedmans-minimalist-axioms-for-set-theory.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Another example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430866/how-strong-is-separation-reflection-of-unbounded-quantifiers.